# Sencha Touch 2 kitchen sink like navigation

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've searched wide and far for this but I don't seem to find any clues on how to do this.
What sencha does quite neatly in its Kitchen Sink is the following:

- Navigationbar docked at the left
- Toolbar docked at the top showing the title of the view.

And I can't seem to figure out how to do this, even with spitting through the source code of the Kitchen Sink. I did find some traces on how to but this is not complete.

```
showViewById: function(id) {
    var nav = this.getNav(),
        view = nav.getStore().getNodeById(id);

    this.showView(view);
    this.setCurrentDemo(view);
    this.hideSheets();
},
```

This is not nearly the whole thing.

Can you suffice me with some sort of tutorial on how to create this type of layout? Or help  me further?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a page that looks like Sencha Touch without actually using it?  That's what I'm trying to figure out, and that is how I interpreted your question, but the answer you accepted seems to suggest I may be wrong about this.

Comment: @Michael If you look at the Kitchensink of Sencha Touch http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/examples/kitchensink/ you see the special navigation it has. I would like the same in Sencha Touch 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the Main.js file (Kitchensink.view.tablet.Main). This class basically, creates the layout you are talking about.. it is straight forward:

```
items: [
    {       // This is the content area... 
        id: 'launchscreen',
        cls : 'card',
        scrollable: true,
        html: 'Home page content'
    },
    { 
        // The left navigation
        id: 'mainNestedList',
        xtype : 'nestedlist',
        useTitleAsBackText: false,
        docked: 'left',
        width : 250,
        store: 'Demos'
    },
    {
        // The top toolbar
        id: 'mainNavigationBar',
        xtype : 'titlebar',
        docked: 'top',
        title : 'Kitchen Sink',
        items: {
            xtype : 'button',
            id: 'viewSourceButton',
            hidden: true,
            align : 'right',
            ui    : 'action',
            action: 'viewSource',
            text  : 'Source'
        }
    }
]
```

This should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks this gives me the order I wanted :), and I can just switch views in the launch-screen that gives me the functionality I wanted.